Type 'SolanaNftAnchor' is missing the following properties from type 'Idl': address, metadata
Hi I am new to solana and i am testing my mint nft contract , while testing when i import my program using :
import { SolanaNftAnchor } from "../target/types/solana_nft_anchor";

It gives me an error:
Type 'SolanaNftAnchor' does not satisfy the constraint 'Idl'.
Type 'SolanaNftAnchor' is missing the following properties from type 'Idl': address, metadata

While the json in /target/idl/solana-nft-anchor.json contains metadata and address but
/target/types/solana-nft-anchor.ts doesnt.
anchor : 0.30.0
Program is successfully Deployed

As per this answer, it's because the IDL spec was rewritten with the 0.0.30 release and it's incompatible with previous versions of anchor.
Please update your anchor TS client version to 0.0.29 "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.29.0",

yes exactly i am importing same like this. and i actually follow your tutorial.

could you share the repo? Other thing to try, 1. restart the TS dev server. 2. run anchor test to regenerate the idl and types from the build step. 3. downgrade to a lower version of anchor, preferably the one specified on the tutorial

I didnt find the anchor version in tutorial but for sure ill share the repo link : https://github.com/MohammadAbuzar945/Solana-NFTMint-Program.git

FYI: I just try all three methods but didnt work for me.

check edited answer @MohammadAbuzar

IDL issue is resolved by downgrading the anchor version but now below.

mints nft!:
Error: AnchorError caused by account: metadata_account. Error Code: ConstraintAddress. Error Number: 2012. Error Message: An address constraint was violated.
Program log: Left:
Program log: 3u6A6KcvfFMFE3FKx7SUws7mYt52KVQsc6KJTaPucsWC
Program log: Right:
Program log: 2S3qnmEhRENgCTceda9s7u5dySZrsiFd2W6RC8dC9cvE

This is now i am getting below error ,  You can refer my code using above link

@MohammadAbuzar use the provided code snippet from the tutorial, this line is causing the error address=find_metadata_account(&mint.key()).0,. Update it correctly as shown here https://github.com/Calyptus-Learn/solana-nft-anchor/blob/e5fb0feedf1a737a6d79e2d4c86b0edcb3280930/programs/solana-nft-anchor/src/lib.rs#L107
